# $var(T(X_1$,...,$X_n)) = 1/n var(X_1)$ (for $n \to \infty$): When does that hold?

Tags: variance, estimation

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be an i.i.d. random sample, and $T(X_1,...,X_n)$ a statistic. In a book (The Jackknife and the Bootstrap by Shao and Tu) I read, that under certain regularity conditions, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} var(T(X_1,...,X_n)) = \frac{1}{n} var(X_1)$$ does hold. But it's not explained which conditions are meant.

Is the euqality true for T being a linear Funktion of the smaple mean?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please remember to write your math symbols between $ signs to allow legibility! I will do it for you this time so that you can have an example of how this works. I am 100% sure the answer to your question is "yes", but I don't exactly know how to justify, so I'll let the experts talk